# Setting proxy for Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I need to config proxy credential for GA4 Client library to pass it from http proxy server, unfortunately there isn't any rich documentation for this purpose on the web (or maybe I couldn't find them)

[Google Analytics Data API(GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#.net)

```
using Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta;
using System.Net;

// Config Proxy Credential
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy([proxy_url], [bypass]);
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential([username], [password]);


// Google Analytics configuration
BetaAnalyticsDataClient client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.Create();
RunReportRequest request = new RunReportRequest
{
  Property = "properties/" + propertyId,
  Dimensions = { new Dimension{ Name="city"}, },
  Metrics = { new Metric{ Name="activeUsers"}, },
  DateRanges = { new DateRange{ StartDate="2020-03-31", EndDate="today"}, },
};

// Make the request
var response = client.RunReport(request);
```

I have tried to assign object proxy to BetaAnalyticsDataClient or RunReportRequest object but I can't find it and I don't know how to use proxy configuration for GA4 library.

Comment: You may want to cross post this over on the GitHub page. [google-cloud-dotnet](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues)